# how to get lists length within foreach

Tags: tcl

```
set listA "A B C"
set listB "D E"

set lists "listA listB" 
foreach l $lists { puts "$l: [llength $l]"}
```

It prints

```
listA: 1
ListB: 1
```

and not

```
listA: 3
listB: 2
```

Comment: @ikegami outside the foreach llength works fine. It is only substitution in loop which is not working. I tried subst but not getting desired output.

Comment: I see. Sorry I couldn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `$l` in the foreach loop is the *name* of a variable, not the *value* of a variable.

When you have a variable containing the name (not value) of another variable, it creates a redirection problem that you can fix a few ways.  I like to use `set` with just one argument to retrieve the value of the variable name:

```
set listA "A B C"
set listB "D E"

set lists "listA listB" 
foreach l $lists {
    set this_list [set $l]
    puts "$l: [llength $this_list]"
}
```

Another option is save the multiple lists into an associate array...

```
set my_array(listA) "A B C"
set my_array(listB) "D E"
set lists "listA listB"
foreach l $lists {
    set this_list $my_array($l)
    puts "$l: [llength $this_list]"
}
```

..or in a dictionary:

```
set my_dict [dict create listA "A B C" listB "D E"]
set lists [dict keys $my_dict]
foreach l $lists {
    set this_list [dict get $my_dict $l]
    puts "$l: [llength $this_list]"
}
```

In all the above examples, creating a variable `this_list` is not necessary, but just to emphasis getting the value of the variable name contained in `$l`.

Answer (score 2):

Yet Another Way to map a string to the variable with that name is using [`upvar`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/upvar.html) with a stack level of 0:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

set listA {A B C}
set listB {D E}

set lists {listA listB}
foreach l $lists {
    upvar 0 $l this_list
    puts "$l: [llength $this_list]"
}
```

(More useful when you're dealing with a proc wanting to work with a variable in its caller's scope that's been passed by name, but it works at the same stack level too if needed)